# check non string value in java

Tags: java

i am not able to check the non string value such as a-z and A-Z using public method

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your First Name: ");
String First_name = input.nextLine();


Scanner last = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your Last Name: ");
String Last_name = last.nextLine();
```

here is public method

```
public static boolean check_non_string_value (String First_name, String Last_name){
  // dont know how to check the input here
}
```

Comment: Check out regular expressions.

Comment: What are you checking?

Comment: I think you mean non alphabetic character instead of non string value.

Comment: search about regular expressions and pattern matching and also string tokenizer

Comment: I would like to point out that limiting valid first and last names to only contain A-Z is questionable in all but the most insultingly narrow-minded contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method valid for a-z and A-Z characters

```
public static boolean check_non_string_value (String First_name, String Last_name){
   if(First_name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")&&Last_name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
          system.out.println("Valid input");
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

This method valid for all word characters

```
public static boolean check_non_string_value (String First_name, String Last_name){
   if(First_name.matches("\\w")&&Last_name.matches("\\w")){
          system.out.println("Valid input");
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: This matches only a single letter.

Comment: `\w`is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` so you will match `my_nam3` but not `Jérémy`.

Comment: No need for `[\\w]`. `\\w` is enough. Also this will also match digits and `_`.

Comment: Well there are still issues here. 1. You need to return a boolean from both of these methods. 2. It would be a much better idea (especially if this method will be called often) to pre-compile this regex so as to avoid the redundancy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions but it's also relatively simple to just loop over each string yourself and use [`Character.isLetter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) to check each character:

```
for (char c : firstName.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isLetter(c))
        return false;
}

for (char c : lastName.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isLetter(c))
        return false;
}

return true;
```

Note that I've used more conventional names: `firstName` and `lastName`. You should always try to follow Java's naming conventions (i.e. use [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)). Your method name should also be `checkNonStringValue`.

With regular expressions, you could do something like:

```
private static final Pattern letters = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}+");

...
    return letters.matcher(firstName).matches() &&
           letters.matcher(lastName).matches();
```

`\p{Alpha}` is a pre-defined character class meaning `[a-zA-Z]`. See [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details.